# How can I apologize?

Tags: support

I posted and answered a question which was based on another question which had been put on Hold as asking for an opinion. I thought that it was because the question asked "what do you think" at the end. So I reworded the question and my question was put on hold as also being off topic. I wish to apologize for that since it was apparently inflammatory, but I still am unsure why it is off topic. I apologize for any dissention I may have caused and guess I still have a lot of learning to do.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there was no dissension here. I just gained the impression that you made the new post because you couldn't answer the old post in time before it was closed. If that's not quite the case then sorry for the rebuke. If that is the case, then yes, that is bad form.

I don't think you really need to apologize. It's on hold now. Maybe try to make the edits David Stratton suggested and it will be reopened.

I think you are turning out to be a pretty good user and I doubt you upset anybody.

Comment: @ Fredsbend Thank you.